# Connect to multiple netstream in the same video object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, rtmp, netstream

Is it possible to have a same Video object ( and perhaps StageVideo) connected to multiple NetStream's objects?

It's videoconferencing app, in which all members can speak ( So multiple audio sources) but should not hear themselves (that's why I don't join them in a single stream).

That's what I tried:

```
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
ns.client = this;
ns.play(streamName1);
ns2 = new NetStream(nc);
...
ns2.play(streamName2);

video.attachNetStream(ns);
video.attachNetStream(ns2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At max 1 NetStream can be attached to 1 Video object. To make video conferencing type of app. you'd need to have multiple video objects (1 for each party you want to show) and attach appropriate netstream object.